# Android fitbit integration

Tags: android, fitbit

Hi I followed fitbit documentation to integrate fitbit into my app. My problem is once I authenticated the application means it is not redirecting me to my andropid activity. I show my codes

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id="
                        + cliend id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&scope=" + "activity";
                Intent oauthIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(oauthIntent);
            }
        });
```

in my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="MyExample4" />
            </intent-filter>
```

It is taking me to my redirect page.Can anyone come across this problem means please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with fitbit but from what I can see in your code i can say that your intent filter is not complete. You should probably make the intent filter match the `redirect_uri` that you embed in the authentication URL.

Once you implement that and the user correctly authenticates the browser will navigate to `redirect_uri` and with the correct `intent-filter` you'll be able to open that in your app.

The code could be as follows:

Set your `redirect_uri` to `my-fitbit-app://my.fitbit.app/handle_auth`

In your `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="my-fitbit-app" />
                <data android:host="my.fitbit.app" />
                <data android:path="/handle_auth" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: I am not able to connect to the default internet browser of the Android device. It's working fine with Chrome browser. Any help?